# How to get <pre> tag contents using preg_match_all?

Tags: php, preg-match, web-scraping, preg-match-all, scrape

I need to scrap the webspage inside the `<pre>` tag contents. i am using `preg_match_all` function but its not working.

My Scraping Website `<pre>` tag content is given below.

```
<pre># Mon Jul 22 03:10:03 CDT 2013

99.46.177.18
99.27.119.169
99.254.168.132
99.245.96.210
99.245.29.38
99.240.245.97
99.239.100.211
<pre>
```

Php file

**Updated**

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.infiltrated.net/blacklisted');
preg_match_all ("/<pre>([^`]*?)<\/pre>/", $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
exit;
```

My php file returns empty array. i know my `preg_match_all` function is a problem.

how can i get the pre tag contents. please guide me.

Edit Question

I can run @Pieter script. but its returns only `Array()`

My script is given below.

```
    <?php
    $url = 'http://www.infiltrated.net/blacklisted';
    $data = new DOMDocument();
    $data->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
    $xpath = new DomXpath($data);

    $pre_tags = array();
    foreach($xpath->query('//pre') as $node){
    $pre_tags[] = $node->nodeValue; 
    }

print_r($pre_tags);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: use a html parser to do these types of work

Comment: @DevZer0 how can i use html parser please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. This http://www.infiltrated.net/blacklisted url is loading from one text file.so only the pre tags shows in the page source. so i am using this method.

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('http://www.infiltrated.net/blacklisted'));
print_r($array);
```

Finally its working greet.

Answer (score 2):

Use the PHP functions to loop through DOM. Using Regex-patterns for HTML tags is strongly discouraged.

Try this code:

```
$data = new DOMDocument();
$data->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
$xpath = new DomXpath($data);

$pre_tags = array();
foreach($xpath->query('//pre') as $node){
    $pre_tags[] = $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Or try PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, see: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: http://www.infiltrated.net/blacklisted  this is my url. ican check this. but its not working. please check it

Comment: Oke, it's working fine on my system when I copy the code of your URL in a local file. Can you have a look at the result of `$data`?

Comment: See edit, you can try it with the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

Comment: Hi @Pieter i can update my question. my response only Array()

Comment: this is only $data response DOMDocument Object ( )

Comment: Use `var_dump()` of `print_r()`, not `echo()`.

Comment: Thanks @Pieter. I got a answer write now. please see my answer.Thanks for your responses. +1 up for you.

Comment: Ah oke. I copied the source code of your URL to a local file and it was working then. ;-)